# How to serialize the many-to-many fields in DRF?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have three tables in models.py:

```
class literature_info(models.Model):
    pmid = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=25)
    publication = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.pmid
    
class dataset_info(models.Model):
    dataset_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=25)
    literature = models.ManyToManyField(literature_info, through='literature_dataset', blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.dataset_id

class literature_dataset(models.Model):
    literature_info = models.ForeignKey(literature_info, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dataset_info = models.ForeignKey(dataset_info, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When I try to access the literature id from dataset_info table, I serialize the fields like this:

```
class literature_info_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = literature_info
        fields = "__all__"

class dataset_literature_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    literature = literature_info_serializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = dataset_info
        fields = ('dataset_id','literature',)
```

It works well, and i get the literature info via dataset.

Now I want to get the literature's datatset from literature_info table, i try to serialize the filed like this:

```
class dataset_info_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = dataset_info
        fields = ('dataset_id',)


class literature_dataset_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dataset_info = dataset_info_serializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = literature_info
        fields = ('pmid', 'dataset_info',)
```

However, it doesn't work this time. So how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the relation in reverse is `dataset_info_set` by default, since you don't specify a [**`related_name=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), this is thus the name of the relation:

```
class literature_dataset_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dataset_info_set = dataset_info_serializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = literature_info
        fields = (
            'pmid',
            'dataset_info_set',
        )
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`literature_info`</s> to `LiteratureInfo`.